# Connect mouse event to wxStaticBitmap (wx 2.8)

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, codeblocks

Hi guys I am here to beat dead horse..

Basically what I am doing is assigning stuff onto a map.

**The map**: A wxStaticBitmap object with the background uploaded by user
**The bomb(lol)**: A wxStaticBitmap object

I managed to merge bomb into arbitrary position on map now with wxMemoryDC + wxDC.

However,I am totally stuck with setting "bomb" with mouse.I want to click somewhere on the map and somehow the bomb will be dropped at the very position I just clicked.

I took a stab with wxMouseEvent and EVT_MOTION(well,like macro ones declared on top)
Obviously they only work with wxWindow or wxFrame.

I was wondering how I am gonna bind mouse event to staticbitmap probably by Connect() but I did not find a proper usage regarding to bomb assignment...

Comment: Please explain what you tried that did not work.  You get the location of the mouse cursor in the frame when the the user clicks, calculate the location in the background bitmap, and place your 'bomb' at that location.  AFAIK it's straightforward.

Comment: hmm the thing is,when hover the cursor at staticbitmap,the mouse event doesnt work.i set two statictexts for showing current coordinates purposes.so when moving on bitmap,the coordinates stop updating.

Comment: This is the problem you need to fix.  Are you using a wxPanel as the parent of your bitmap?  Best to simplify your code as much as possible, then post it, so we don't have to try and guess your problem.

Comment: i'll try if wxpanel as parent works then bother you experts.lol thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is best to create a single wxPanel as the child of the frame, then create all your widgets as children of the wxPanel.  This way most everything works as you naturally expect and you hit fewer gotchas.

Comment: i declared EVT_MOTION(MyFrame::OnCoordUpdate) in event table after modifying interface structrue like wxFrame->wxPanel->Sizers/Components.but the coordinates dont update everywhere in the window.I am wondering what the correct way to declare mouse motion is

Comment: oh probably i declared in wxframe's event table!lol is "BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(panel1, wxPanel)" the right way to declare ?

Answer (score 1):

The best and simplest solution I've found is to Connect own event handler to wxStaticBitmap like this:

```
sb->Connect(wxID_ANY,wxEVT_MOTION,
    wxMouseEventHandler(MyFrame::OnMouse),NULL,this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this to connect mouse-move, mouse left key down and mouse left key up:

```
thiri = new wxStaticBitmap(this, wxID_ANY, wxImage(966, 680), /*image start point*/wxPoint(0,0), /* canvas size to display*/ wxSize(966, 680));

// mouse event on image
thiri->Connect( wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, wxMouseEventHandler(Panel::OnMouseLeftDown), NULL, this );
thiri->Connect( wxEVT_MOTION, wxMouseEventHandler(Panel::OnMouseMove), NULL, this );
thiri->Connect( wxEVT_LEFT_UP, wxMouseEventHandler(Panel::OnMouseLeftUp), NULL, this);
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `Connect()` in 2018. Use `Bind()` instead.